Pinescript dynamic_requests Plotting
Here is my first attempt using dynamic_requests to plot prices from multiple symbols (by editing code snippets from the
doco on the new DYNAMIC_REQUESTS functionality).
Although the brute force method of creating a dummy variable for each price and then plotting the dummies does work, I was hoping to find a concise way (within a loop or using a series) to plot all of the price values for all symbols.   The last line was a kludge hoping that even plotchar could display all symbols as characters, but it only displays values of the last symbol POLYX using a for loop.  I am aware of the difficulty/impossibility of using plot() in a for loop in pinescript, and am probably asking for a miracle...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
//@version=5
indicator("Dynamic Requests Plotting", dynamic_requests = true, format = format.price)

//@variable An array of "string" values representing different symbols to request. 
var array<string> symbols = array.from(
     "KAS", "GLMR", "DOGE", "POLYX"
 )

//@variable An array containing the data retrieved for each requested symbol.  
array<float> requestedData = array.new<float>()

// Retrieve closing price for each symbol in the `symbols` array and push the results into the `requestedData` array. 
for symbol in symbols
    float data = request.security("BYBIT:" + symbol + "USDT.P", timeframe.period, close)
    requestedData.push(data)

float v0 = requestedData.get(0)
float v1 = requestedData.get(1)
float v2 = requestedData.get(2)
float v3 = requestedData.get(3)

plot(v0, "KAS", color.yellow,   1)
plot(v1, "GLMR", color.gray,   1)
plot(v2, "DOGE", color.teal,   1)
//plot(v3, "POLYX",  color.maroon, 1)

series float prices = na
int i = 0
for symbol in symbols
    prices := requestedData.get(i)
    i += 1

plotchar(prices,title="Prices",color=color.red,location=location.absolute)

